# How to replace specific character in Nasm procedure

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16

I want to replace white-spaces in dbyte with '#' character, and
db should be passed to the procedure by stack.

I've written next snippet and replacing is working, but I can't understand how to pass db to procedure `func` properly.

```
org 0x100 
    push array
    call func
    mov bp, sp 
    mov bx, [bp]
    ret 

loop:
    mov al, byte[bx+si]
    cmp al, 0
     jz func
    cmp al , ' '
     jnz loop
    mov byte[bx+si], '#'
    inc si
    jmp loop
    ret

func:  
    push bp  
    mov bp, sp  
    mov bx, [bp + 4]    
    call loop
    mov [bp + 4], bx
    pop bp  
    ret 4 

array db "a b c", 0
```

Comment: `push array` is correct for the common but inefficient calling convention you're using, of passing an arg on the stack for that function.  Inside `func`, you should be able to see with a debugger that `BX` gets the address of the `array` label.  Probably your bug is that you don't set SI before using it in `loop`.  Also that `ret 4` at the end of `func` pops 4 bytes, but you only pushed 2.    Without a proper [mcve] including what actually happens, it's hard to say more than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Several problems

> ```
> push array
> call func
> ;
> ret 4
> ```

This is 16-bit code and so *array* is pushed as a word. The `ret 4` should be `ret 2` instead. Note that your *array* is actually a zero-terminated *string*.

> ```
> mov al, byte[bx+si]
> ```

This can not work if you didn't clear `SI` beforehand.

> ```
> cmp al, 0
> jz func
> ```

You are in code that you've `call`ed. You shouldn't jump back to the caller like this!

> ```
> cmp al , ' '
> jnz loop
> ```

This jump to the top misses the increment on `SI`.

> ```
> mov [bp + 4], bx
> ```

This is redundant since the argument wasn't modified. Moreover you're going to discard it anyway.

> ```
> mov bp, sp 
> mov bx, [bp]
> ```

Is this useful? It just loads the return address for the program termination that follows.

> ```
> ret
> ```

This way of terminating the program depends on a correct stack. That will not always be the case! DOS programs are better terminated through:

```
mov ax, 4C00h
int 21h
```

---

### Putting it together

```
 org  256

 push MyString
 call Func
 mov  bp, sp 
 mov  bx, [bp]
 mov  ax, 4C00h  ;Program termination
 int  21h

Loop:
 mov  al, byte[bx+si]
 cmp  al, 0
 je   EndOfLoop
 cmp  al, ' '
 jne  NotASpace
 mov  byte[bx+si], '#'
NotASpace:
 inc  si
 jmp  Loop
EndOfLoop:
 ret

;Clobbers AL, BX, SI
Func:  
 push bp  
 mov  bp, sp  
 mov  bx, [bp + 4]
 xor  si, si
 call Loop
 pop  bp  
 ret  2

MyString db "a b c", 0
```